# Proof without using Green's Identity

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am a TA for an Analysis II (i.e. Multidimentional Mathematical Analysis) class and the professor recently left a question to show $$\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial \nu} (x-y)dS_y=1$$ for a bounded domain $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any $x \in \Omega$, where $\Gamma$ is the fundamental solution of Laplace equation and $\nu$ denotes the outer normal of $\partial \Omega$. 
I am clear that this is trivial using Green's second identity by taking one function as $1$ and the other as $\Gamma$ but the Green's Representation has not been introduced by the professor up to now. So I want a proof without using Green's Theorem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the divergence theorem allowed?

Comment: I think the Gauss-Ostrogradsky's Theorem is allowed, since it is very basic for calculating the integral on surface.

Comment: Let $r > 0$ such that the closed ball $\overline{B}(x;r)$ is contained in $\Omega$, and define $\Omega_r := \Omega \setminus B(x;r)$. Try applying the theorem over the domain $\Omega_r$ first.

Comment: OK I get it, thank you!